# how to call python code in javascript to display bar chart

Tags: javascript, python

i have written python code which gives me i/p to chart(json data) but i am not getting how to get these data in my javascript.

i want to display it in google app engine

i want to do it in same way as we can do it with PHP.

Comment: will you post the codes?

Answer (score 0):

As I've posted a few times already, if you want Python to be PHP-like, try [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Flask is dead-simple, extremely powerful, and intuitive. I prefer it over PHP for *soo* many reasons, but mainly because PHP is not Python.

Here's what I mean by simple and intuitive. I can't really explain it in words, so here's an example script:

**File:** script.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('index.html', message = range(0, 10000))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')
```

**File:** index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  {% for hello in message %}
    <p>{{ hello }}</p>
  {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty sure it's usable with Google App Engine, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Where is the link between the html and the python code here? Just curious; I'd like to test out your example.

Comment: That HTML is not *just* HTML. It's like a PHP file. To run it, create both files (name them accordingly), install Flask, and just run `python script.py`. Then, just navigate to `localhost:5000` and you're good to go!

Comment: The link is here: `return render_template('index.html', message = range(0, 10000))`. It renders the template file with the variable `message` set to a bunch of numbers. `@app.route('/')` just makes the next declared function run when you visit `localhost/`.

Comment: Sorry if I'm explaining it a bit crudely. You can find a simpler example on the homepage: http://flask.pocoo.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Google charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)?